# The meaning of an explanatory variable in computing accuracy of a prediction model

Tags: r, logistic, predictive-models

I am following the logistic regression predictive modeling example found [here](https://mdsr-book.github.io/mdsr2e/ch-modeling.html), chapter 10. To the `pred` object the variable `capital_gain` is set, I assume, as a predictor variable. The response variable is `income` and its levels are "<=50k" and ">50k".

If I remove `capital_gain` from the `pred` object, the `accuracy(pred, income, income_null)` gives the same output, and the confusion matrix remains unchanged as well.

```
library(yardstick)
pred <- train %>%
  select(income, capital_gain) %>% #why 'capital_gain' is here? 
  bind_cols(
    predict(mod_null, new_data = train, type = "class")
  ) %>%
  rename(income_null = .pred_class)
accuracy(pred, income, income_null)
```

```
#Confusion matrix
confusion_null <- pred %>%
  conf_mat(truth = income, estimate = income_null)
confusion_null
```

But the logistic regression model produces a result, that is only a little bit different from running the model without removing `capital_gain` from the `pred` object.

This first picture is produced with `capital_gain` in the `pred` object.

[image]

This second picture is produced without `capital_gain` in the `pred` object. As you can see, there are only small differences.

[image]

So, I am trying to understand what is the meaning of having `capital_gain` in the `pred` object. Why removing it doesn't affect the prediction accuracy nor the confusion matrix, and why it affects the scatter plot?

Data:

```
census <- read_csv(
  url,
  col_names = c(
    "age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education", 
    "education_1", "marital_status", "occupation", "relationship", 
    "race", "sex", "capital_gain", "capital_loss", "hours_per_week", 
    "native_country", "income"
  )
) %>%
  mutate(income = factor(income))

library(tidymodels)
set.seed(364)
n <- nrow(census)
census_parts <- census %>%
  initial_split(prop = 0.8)

train <- census_parts %>%
  training()
```

This is the regression model:

```
mod_log_1 <- logistic_reg(mode = "classification") %>%
  set_engine("glm") %>%
  fit(income ~ capital_gain, data = train)

train_plus <- train %>%
  mutate(high_earner = as.integer(income == ">50K"))

ggplot(train_plus, aes(x = capital_gain, y = high_earner)) + 
  geom_count(
    position = position_jitter(width = 0, height = 0.05), 
    alpha = 0.5
  ) + 
  geom_smooth(
    method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"), 
    color = "dodgerblue", lty = 2, se = FALSE
  ) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5), linetype = 3) + 
  scale_x_log10(labels = scales::dollar)
```

This post is migrated from Stack Overflow

EDIT: I tried to clarify my question

Comment: "*So what is the meaning of having it there?*" I don't understand your question. If your goal is prediction, then all that matters is whether the variable is useful for prediction or not, which you can quantify. If it's not useful because the same information is contained within some other variable or combination of variables, you can omit it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mkt. I tried to clarify my question with an edit

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how your code matches up with your plots, or whether your question is about code or concept. For e.g. you say "*This second picture is produced without capital_gain in its above mentioned place*" but you show code for only one model and plot, so we're missing part of the picture.

Comment: Are you trying to understand why there's a good relationship between `capital_gain` and `high_earner` even when `capital_gain` is not in the underlying model? If that is your question, then a plot of `capital_gain` against `income` might help explain things.

Comment: Actually, I now see that `income` is being turned into the response variable `high_earner` by discretising it (we strongly advise against that here, but let's set that aside for now). If that is correct, then the rest doesn't make any sense. It would help a lot it you organised your code and explained what you are doing clearly.

Comment: In removing *capital gain* from the first model code, doesn't that implicitly revert to an *intercept only* model? In the absence of metrics of observed performance, this might suggest that *capital gain* is, at best, weakly predictive

Comment: @mkt I again tried to formulate my question into a clearer form. I hope it now makes more sense

Comment: @MikeHunter Thanks for your comment. You might be correct with your point of view. I edited the question so that it would be easier to understand. You might want to have another look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here mod_null is an intercept-only model. You could pass any features you like into that model and it will just ignore them, and return the same value it always does. Passing capital_gains into a null model doesn't change the output at all. You correctly observed that the results don't change.

The plots look different because you are applying random jitter to the points. Note that your plot shows logistic regression values greater than 1 and less and 0, which is impossible. You're showing the exact same data twice with different random vertical offset applied to the points.